# In Jmeter, How to generate unique order and pass it in request body. The request body is been sent by CSV file

Tags: api, jmeter, scripting

**Im passing multiple request bodies for an API using RequestBody.CSV file.**
[image]

**This requestbody have orderID and it should be a UUID every time. I'm passing this OrderID using User Parameters** [image]

**And replaced them in the CSV file like this**  [image]

**This is the CVS data set config used** [image]

**When I run the test, the orderID is not generating random number and it is passed as**
[image]

**This is the HTTP request im sending** [image]

**How can I send random orderID in the request body.**

Answer (score 0):

1. In your CSV file change `${orderID}` to `${__UUID}`, JMeter's [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) generates an unique [UUID v4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) structure each time it's being called.
2. In the HTTP Request sampler change `${requestbody}` to `${__eval(${requestbody})}`, JMeter's [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) evaluates nested [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so an unique UUID will be generated on each iteration of each virtual user

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)